# javascript number literal using exponent

Tags: javascript, numbers, exponent

```
console.log(2E-12); // returns 2E-12
console.log(2E12); // returns 2000000000000
```

Why does line one return 2E-12 and not the same as line two. Is this an illegal way of using the exponent?

Comment: One exponent is positive, the other is negative.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the JavaScript language but rather the implementation of `console.log`.

Comment: @Musa well `console.log("" + 2E-12)` prints the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, `console.log` just uses `toString` to get the rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ECMAScript specification of [toString applied to the Number type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1):

> 7. If 0 < n ≤ 21, return the String consisting of the most significant n digits of the decimal representation of s, followed by a decimal point ‘.’, followed by the remaining k−n digits of the decimal representation of s.
>
> 8. If −6 < n ≤ 0, return the String consisting of the character ‘0’, followed by a decimal point ‘.’, followed by −n occurrences of the character ‘0’, followed by the k digits of the decimal representation of s.
>
> 9. Otherwise, if k = 1, return the String consisting of the single digit of s, followed by lowercase character ‘e’, followed by a plus sign ‘+’ or minus sign ‘−’ according to whether n−1 is positive or negative, followed by the decimal representation of the integer abs(n−1) (with no leading zeroes).

`n` is effectively the exponent of the number. So this says that if the exponent is between `-7` and `21` the number should be displayed normally, otherwise exponential notation should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The renderer is being clever. If you try `console.log(2E-6)`, you'll see it does what you're expecting. `console.log(2E-7)` does not...at least in Chrome and the current version of IE. Someone decided exponential notation was more legible for long fractional values.

Additionally, note that the `2e-12` you're getting is a number, not a string.

```
> console.log(2e-12*2e5)
4e-7
```

Comment: And for positive exponents, it starts using exponential notation at `2e+21`

Comment: so basically this is a bug?

Comment: It looks like it's specified this way in ECMAScript 6. See http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type